# How can I reinstall Grunt in a yeoman project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, yeoman

Something happened to my Grunt installation, and I have no idea what it was.  I am using Yeoman to scaffold my app, but today I started getting many Grunt errors.  For instance, I now get the following when I run `Grunt Test`:

```
Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'base64-js'
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-signature'
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module './lib/js-yaml.js'
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'jshint'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module './source-map/source-map-generator'
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /Users/Documents/Git/client/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/cdnjs-cdn-data/external/cdnjs.json: Unexpected end of input
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /Users/Documents/Git/client/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:390
>> });
>>    
>> Unexpected end of input
Loading "ngmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'estraverse'
Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /Users/Documents/Git/client/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:950
>> });
>>  ^
>> Unexpected token )
Loading "usemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /Users/Documents/Git/client/node_modules/grunt-usemin/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:5520
>> });
>> ^
>> Unexpected token }
Loading "css_sprite.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'async'
Warning: Task "autoprefixer" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

I have updated NPM, I have tried to update Grunt, I have tried to install all of those packages that Grunt can not find.  Is there a way to nuke and repave Grunt and install a brand new copy for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the error messages...for e.g. yours say...

> Warning: Task "autoprefixer" not found. Use --force to continue.

Try installing grunt-autoprefixer...

```
npm install grunt-autoprefixer --save
```

Then run `grunt test` again...

You get other error messages...find the stuff that is missing...install it via npm. At times you may have to google for the correct package names...

Comment: At first I thought I would do that, but all of the "missing" packages are actually installed. Additionally, I tried to run `npm install` to reinstall them all, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 8):

You might have partially installed npm packages cached on your machine.

Try running `npm cache clean`

Then delete the project packages installed:
`rm -rf node_modules`

Then try running `npm install` one more time.

Comment: This resolved my issue - I had some funkiness with npm after a failed npm update. The above steps work, thank you Isaac